# Check if post exists by title and taxonomy term?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, taxonomy

Below code is to check if a post exists by looking at the title row in `wpdb`.

```
function post_exists($title) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '" . $title . "'", 'ARRAY_A');
}
```

How would I check if a post exists by title and taxonomy term?
For example, I have a custom taxonomy "`genres`" and taxonomy term "`horror`". I want to check if a post exists by post title, and also the term "horror".

I've been struggling with this for a couple days.

Answer (score 0):

> taxonomy and term are stored in `wp_term_taxonomy` and `wp_terms`
>   table so you need to join then to get the desired output.

I have modified your function like below.

```
function wh_post_exists($title) {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT posts.ID
        FROM $wpdb->posts AS posts
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS term_relationships ON posts.ID = term_relationships.object_id
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS term_taxonomy ON term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms AS terms ON term_taxonomy.term_id = terms.term_id
        WHERE term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'genres'
           AND terms.slug = 'horror'
           AND posts.post_type = 'post'
           AND posts.post_title = %s", $title);
    $result = $wpdb->get_row($query, 'ARRAY_A');

    //checking error msg
    if ($wpdb->last_error !== '') {
        $wpdb->print_error();
        die('-- code execution discontinued --');
    }
    if (count($result) > 0) {
        return TRUE; //exists
    } else {
        return FALSE; //does not exists
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = get_posts(array(
'showposts' => -1,
'post_type' => 'post', // post Type any even you can use custom post type
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'genres', // Taxonomy name like genres
    'field' => 'name',
    'terms' => array('horror')) // Taxonomy term 
),
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC'));

if(!empty($result)){ // Term related Post exist then do code
}
```